# JQ: How to turn output of array selector back into an array?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm using the select function with jq to parse for items in a list that contain a certain value.  I want the resulting output to be a json list, but jq gives me the objects individually:

Example:

```
$ a='{                                                                                   
  "FOO": {                                                                                    
    "name": "Donald",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  "BAR": {
    "name": "Walt",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  "BAZ": {
    "name": "Jack",
    "location": "Whereever"
  }
}'

$ echo $a | jq '.[] | select(.location=="Stockholm")' 
{
  "name": "Donald",
  "location": "Stockholm"
}
{
  "name": "Walt",
  "location": "Stockholm"
}
```

Instead I want the output to be a json list like this:

```
[  
  {
    "name": "Donald",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  },
  {
    "name": "Walt",
    "location": "Stockholm"
  }
]
```

How can I do this with jq?

Comment: Did you already try surrounding it in brackets ```echo $a | jq '[ .[] | select(.location=="Stockholm") ]' ```

Comment: BTW, `echo $a` is a frequent cause of heartburn. Always quote your expansions: `echo "$a"`, to avoid [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can stick square brackets around any expression to gather all its outputs into an array.

```
[.[] | select(.location=="Stockholm")]
```

Sometimes it makes sense not to break up the input array in the first place, but use map to transform it:

```
map(select(.location=="Stockholm"))
```